# How to generate nice looking algorithm tables in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am looking for a way to create nice looking algorithm tables, which are mostly generated in latex documents and used in scientific papers e.g.

[image: Scientific paper]

Is there a good tutorial how to do it?

I become desperate when I try to reduce the height of the first row in a table in MS Word 2016, although I set all the height parameters and the ceiling parameters to 0, there is plenty of space after a text (marked with red crosses).

My Word problem:

[image]

Comment: Did you check the paragraph spacing "After" setting?

Comment: Thanks, meanwhile i've found another solution [Table Properties -> Row -> Row height to 1 cm -> Row Height is "Exact" (not at least)], but yours is definitely better.

Comment: Is your problem solved now with Tanya's suggestion, or do you have other issue too?

Comment: its solved now, but i can't close the question

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for an answer to this, you might find the following YouTube video helpful

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SR-Fm1iG2fk

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Select the row then set the **Alignment** to **Align Center Left** and check if it is what you want.
[image]